# Use of React getDerivedStateFromProps()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm exploring React and am somewhat confused over lifecycle methods and parent-child communication. Specifically, I'm trying to create a component which wraps a select element and adds an input box when the "Other" option is selected. I have implemented this using `getDerivedStateFromProps()` but according to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) this lifecycle method should rarely be used. Hence my question: is there another pattern I should be aware of and use in this case?

This is my code, the value and options are passed down as props, as is the `handleChange()` method of the parent component. So when changes are made in the select or input elements, the parent component state is updated first and a new value is passed down through `props.value`.

```
export default class SelectOther extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
        let optionIndex = -1;
        for (let i = 0; i < props.options.length; i++) {
            if (props.options[i].value === props.value) {
                optionIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (optionIndex > -1) {
            return {
                selected: props.options[optionIndex].value,
                text: "",
                showInput: false
            };
        } else {
            return {
                selected: "",
                text: props.value,
                showInput: true
            };
        }
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.props.handleChange({
            "target": {
                "name": this.props.name,
                "value": e.target.value
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>{ this.props.label }</label>
                <select name={ this.props.name } value={ this.state.selected } onChange={ this.handleChange }>
                    {
                        this.props.options.map(option => <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>)
                    }
                    <option value="">Other</option>
                </select>
                {
                    this.state.showInput &&
                        <div>
                            <label>{ this.props.label } (specify other)</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={ this.state.text } onChange={ this.handleChange }></input>
                        </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify by not having SelectOther have any state, here is an example of how you can pass a function that dispatches an action to change values. Because SelectOther is a pure component it won't needlessly re render:

```js
//make this a pure component so it won't re render
const SelectOther = React.memo(function SelectOther({
  label,
  name,
  value,
  options,
  handleChange,
}) {
  console.log('in render',name, value);
  const showInput = !options
    .map(o => o.value)
    .includes(value);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <select
        name={name}
        value={showInput ? '' : value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {options.map(option => (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
        <option value="">Other</option>
      </select>
      {showInput && (
        <div>
          <label>{label} (specify other)</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name={name}
            className="form-control"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  //create options once during App life cycle
  const options = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      { value: 'one', label: 'one label' },
      { value: 'two', label: 'two label' },
    ],
    []
  );
  //create a state to hold input values and provide
  //  a reducer to create new state based on actions
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (state, { type, payload }) => {
      //if type of action is change then change the
      //  payload.name field to payload.value
      if (type === 'CHANGE') {
        const { name, value } = payload;
        return { ...state, [name]: value };
      }
      return state;
    },
    //initial state for the inputs
    {
      my_name: '',
      other_input: options[0].value,
    }
  );
  //use React.useCallback to create a callback
  //  function that doesn't change. This would be
  //  harder if you used useState instead of useReducer
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'CHANGE',
        payload: {
          name,
          value,
        },
      });
    },
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <SelectOther
        label="label"
        name="my_name"
        value={state.my_name}
        options={options}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
      <SelectOther
        label="other"
        name="other_input"
        value={state.other_input}
        options={options}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I could have uses useState in App but then I have to use [useEventCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192552/1641941) or do a useState for every input value. The [following documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) comes up with the useEventCallback pattern and then immediately after states that **we don’t recommend this pattern** so that's why I came up with the useReducer solution instead.